# how to restrict addition of attributes for a tag based on a condition in xslt code

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How can we create attributes based on some condition in xslt.

My input xml has a tag:

```
          <track external="http://mysite.com"  />
              or
           <track  local="/myfolder" />
```

and in this 'track element either external or local attribute appears but not either of these and i have to convert it into

```
       <a xhtml:href="@external value" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
```

if 'extrenal' attribute occurs for 'track' element or into

```
       <a xlink:href="@local value" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
```

if 'local'attribute occurs for 'track' element

XSLT tried:

```
     <a xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">      

      <xsl:for-each select="child::*" >
        <xsl:choose>

          <xsl:when test="name()='track'">
             <xsl:if test="@local">
            <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">

            <xsl:value-of select="@local" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
               <xsl:if test="@external">
            <xsl:attribute name="xhtml:href">

            <xsl:value-of select="@external" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>

      </a>
```

but exception is thrown as i created attributes for 'a' element based on a condition. This is not accepted in XSLT 1.0, is there any way to make attribute appear for my 'a' element based on some condition in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing preventing you conditionally adding attributes in XSLT 1.0. Incidentally, avoid for-each in XSLT and use templates instead. Here's a dedicated template for `track` nodes.

```
<xsl:template match='track'>

    <a xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <xsl:if test="@local">
            <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@local" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="@external">
            <xsl:attribute name="xhtml:href">
                <xsl:value-of select="@external" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    </a>

</xsl:template>
```

As Tim C mentioned, though, a better pattern would be to handle the different types of incoming attribute via different templates. As much as anything, this is cleaner, as you don't get bogged down in conditional blocks.

```
<xsl:template match='track'>
    <a><xsl:apply-templates select='@*' /></a>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='@local' xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='@external' xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:attribute name="xhtml:href">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

You can see both approaches in action in [this XMLPlayground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/F8yufF).

Answer (score 3):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:mappings>
  <map from="external" to="xhtml"/>
  <map from="local" to="xlink"/>
 </my:mappings>

 <xsl:variable name="vMaps" select="document('')/*/my:mappings/*"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vNamespaces" select="document('')/*/namespace::*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <t><xsl:apply-templates/></t>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="track">
     <xsl:element name="a"
       namespace="{$vNamespaces[name()=$vMaps[@from=name(current()/@*)]/@to]}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{$vMaps[@from=name(current())]/@to}:href"
    namespace="{$vNamespaces[name()=$vMaps[@from=name(current())]/@to]}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
    <track external="http://mysite.com"  />
    <track  local="/myfolder" />
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<t xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xhtml:href="http://mysite.com"/>
   <a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/myfolder"/>
</t>
```

**Do note** This solution has some unique features such as:

1. No conditional instructions are used, so the code is simpler and less error-prone.
2. Pure "push" style is used.
3. THe exact wanted result is produced.

Comment: document('')/*/my:mappings/* is something new that i have learnt from this answer.Thanks a lot.Correct me if i'm wrong, document('') refers current doc and document('')/* refers all tags under root element and document('')/*/my:mappings/ goes into my:mappings right

Comment: @XSLTBeginner: `document('')` is the XML document of the current stylesheet -- this generally is not the "current document" -- the latter means the current *source XML* document -- the one that contains the current node. Also, I think that the currently accepted answer *doesn't* produce the exact wanted result -- please, verify.

Comment: The accepted answer also works fine for my xml.But a small problem with that is if a text node is added before adding attribute nodes to 'a' tag then a exception will be thrown.

Comment: @XSLTBeginner - that is not a problem of what I gave you, that is a requirement of XSLT - attributes must always be added to a node before any physical or text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably make use of of template matching to match the relevant situations. Firstly, instead of using **xsl:for-each** use **xsl:apply-templates**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
```

And then have separate templates to match whether there is a **local** or **external** attribute

```
<xsl:template match="track[@external]">
    <a xhtml:href="{@external}" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="track[@local]">
    <a xlink:href="{@local}" />
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="album">
        <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="track[@external]">
        <a xhtml:href="{@external}" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="track[@local]">
        <a xlink:href="{@local}" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XSLT

```
<album>
   <track external="http://mysite.com"/>
   <track local="/myfolder"/>
</album>
```

The following is output

```
<p xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/">
   <a xhtml:href="http://mysite.com" />
   <a xlink:href="/myfolder" />
</p>
```

Comment: I wanted to do in such a way that i will process 'track' element from my input xml in my xslt and then create a tag 'a' in my XSLT code and construct this element with the corresponding attributes which depend upon the attributes that i encounter in 'track' element.

Comment: so it goes like, building 'a' tag first then check the attributes encountered in 'track' element and then build 'a' tag's corresponding attributes. But your xslt builds entire 'a' tag according to the attributes encountered in 'track' element.

Comment: I would amend my answer, but I think Utkanos has already shown the way to go with his answer!